# How to operate the camera on raspi3?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspicam

My material:
Raspberry 3 + camera (official) purchased together and never used before

Validated interfaces: ssh, vnc serial-console and camera

Added software: Apache, php, mariadb phpmyadmin

I took the following steps in accordance with all the tutorials and documents available:

validation of the camera: `sudo raspi-config`

- installation of the v4l2 driver: `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2`
- check of '/ etc / modules': bcm2835-v4l2 is in the list
- reboot
- test with `vcgencmd get_camera`: `supported = 1 detected = 0`
- an additional test, although unnecessary with `raspistill -v -o test.jpeg` the response ends with the following error messages:

```
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component' vc.ril.camera '(1: ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Camera is not detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed correctly
```

**Important I think** : note the absence of 'video0' in / dev.

I checked the connection of the flat cable several times

Here is.

I don't see what else to do except incriminate the material but I don't know how to test it.
Does somebody have an idea ?

Comment: Most important part of your question is `supported = 1 detected = 0`  that points to a fault with the ribbon cable connecting the camera to your RPi. Have you connected the camera to the wrong connector on your RPi board?

Comment: I agree with your analysis, but, as I specified in the question asked, I am well connected to the 'camera' port and I have already checked several times the orientation of the cord in the connector and its clipping. This is why I wonder about the camera itself.